# Is “checking my résumé” ok?

Tags: conversation, telephone

Is the following sentence correct (when I call a company’s HR department)?

> Could you please call me back after checking my résumé?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the sentence is perfectly fine. However, you may want to substitute *reviewing* for *checking*, however, as *checking* implies there is a right resume and a wrong resume. Since there isn't a right way, *reviewing* works better.